# Authorise a user to add a collection to their userID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-native

I am trying to POST to an endpoint and update a users profile with a collection that is associated with their USERID. I keep getting a `401 unathorized` error

THE ROUTER:

```
router.post(`/newfixture/:id`, async (req, res) => {
  let fixture = new Fixture({
    id: req.body.id,
    homeTeam: req.body.homeTeam,
    awayTeam: req.body.awayTeam,
    date: req.body.date,
    time: req.body.time,
    venue: req.body.venue,
  });
  // save the fixture to the user and return a response
  fixture = await fixture.save({
    id: req.body.id,
    homeTeam: req.body.homeTeam,
    awayTeam: req.body.awayTeam,
    date: req.body.date,
    time: req.body.time,
    venue: req.body.venue,
  });
  if (!fixture) {
    return res.status(404).send("The fixture cannot be created!");
  }
  res.send(fixture);
  console.log("fixture created", fixture);
});
```

Then the call to axios:

```
    axios
      .post(`${baseURL}users/fixtures/newfixture/${id}`, {
        homeTeam: homeTeam,
        awayTeam: awayTeam,
        venue: venue,
        date: date,
        time: time,
      })
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          console.log('     FIXTURE PUT', userProfile);
        } else {
          console.log('     NOPE ', userProfile);
        }
      });
```

Also adding the middleware here

```
const userRoute = require("./routers/users");
app.use(`${api}/users`, userRoute);
```

```
mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@cluster0.svhnchn.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy shit the problem was so stupid.
I was declaring the `authJWT` from another file. Then I was redeclaring it in the `middleware` what an absolute ridiculous issue.

I was redeclaring it here.

```
// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan("tiny"));
app.use(errorHandler);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your endpoint is incorrect

```
.post(`${baseURL}users/fixtures/newfixture/${id}`
```

it should probably be

```
.post(`${baseURL}/users/fixtures/newfixture/${id}`
```

Comment: i wish it was that easy, when I console the url endpoint this is the result. `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/fixtures/newfixture/63692ccee2290b3c57fae6dc`

Comment: @JasonBeedle then it has to do with your mongodb connection setup, you aren't using the right credentials. update your question by adding your mongodb connection code and we can help debug it. don't reveal your correct username and pass though

Comment: I have updated that and added the middleware code.... @otejiri